# How to set a function with dash and subscript

Tags: math-mode, punctuation, subscripts

In

```
$f_3$
```

the subscript is higher than in

```
$f'_3$.
```

So how does one set a function with dash and subscript correctly?

Comment: Normally the adjustment is only needed if `f_3` and `f'_3` appear in the same formula; just do `f^{}_3` in that case. It's not the only case where this trick is needed: look at `a_1a_2^2` and `a_1^{}a_2^{2}`.

Comment: the more usual name for this superscript symbol is "prime".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would input `f'_{3}`.

Beside this: it's a feature of TeX, not a bug, that the subscript position change if there is also a superscript. See Appendix G of the TeXbook. But you can change the fontdimens:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\begin{document}

$\hbox{}$%initialize math 
\fontdimen16\textfont2=2.7pt
\fontdimen17\textfont2=2.7pt
$f^{}_3 f_3 f^{'}_3 f'_3$

\end{document}
```

The change is global, so if you want to revert it you will have to save the original values. There is also a package `subdepth` which does something similar.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I don't see how `f'_{3}` gives a output from `f'_3`. But the global change is helpful.

Comment: `f_3` and `f_{3}` is equivalent, but the braces don't hurt, and as you need them for longer subscripts anyway, it is only consequent to use them always.

Answer (score 4):

Compare `$f^{}_3 f_3 f^{'}_3 f'_3$`

[image]

Comment: Thanks. As mentioned, the second looks out of line to me. For the third the dash seems a bit too high. So I guess the first and last are the ones to go. Strange that LaTeX does not set them in line by default, i.e. $f_3$ and $f'_3$ being in line.